# How to have an always editable column with footable

Tags: contenteditable, footable

I would like to use footable (I've already use footable for its responsive exploding display )and this to show records coming from a database but with a need to have a column (which display the stock quantity of products) that thye user can modify just by typing. Is there any way of having some sort of content editable column....
Any idea will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the column as HTML, which will prevent footable from taking over the content of the cell, and have an `<input type="text" />` for each row.

Something like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th data-type="html">In stock</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td><input type="number" step="any" value="3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Oranges</td>
      <td><input type="number" step="any" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Check the documentation at https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html , look for "Column Options" > "Type" .

After rendering you can attach an event listener to the input fields and send ajax calls accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks , I will use the html type. I tried with a content-editable span and it's working fine

Comment: Please be aware that contenteditable allows for entering HTML as value. For your use-case I would suggest using input as that's the value you are expecting from the field.

Comment: Thanks but the app is under Electron and not sending anything on the net. Only one user so no risk.But anyway I will try to do it safely and use an input (I just tried and it's not more difficult so I'll use it).